# MVC3 Custom EditorFor DateTime and DisplayFormat attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, editorfor

I've created a custom EditorFor DateTime and added a classname to the textbox

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new {  @class = "date-time-picker" })
```

So that I can connect jquery datepicker to it client side

```
$("input.date-time-picker").datetimepicker();
```

The problem is that for the

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:g}")]
```

attribute to work you need to use the built in EditorFor (Or extracting the model metadata and do the same stuff yourself), so whats the best way of overriding the default EditorFor, add the classname and call the built in editorfor so that I can use the **DisplayFormat** attribute

Comment: Try to use a UIHint DataAnnotation for your property. Maybe it can work.

Comment: How exactly? I know that you can use it to specify which view to use.. But how does this help here?

Answer (score 1):

(Question answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I solved it by doing this, but it feels like reinventing the wheel

```
@model DateTime  
@Html.TextBox("", string.Format(ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(x => x, ViewData).DisplayFormatString, Model), new { @class = "date-time-picker" })
```